# MySQL query not giving desired output

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(pickupdatetime, '%m/%y') AS mmyy,
SUM(CASE WHEN (status = 'Canceled' or 'Unconfirmed' or 'Communicating') and (class = 'local') THEN quotedprice ELSE 0 END) AS potentiallocal,
SUM(CASE WHEN (status = 'Closed' or 'Confirmed' or 'Open') and (class = 'local') THEN quotedprice ELSE 0 END) AS actuallocal,

SUM(CASE WHEN (status = 'Canceled' or 'Unconfirmed' or 'Communicating') and (class = 'travel') THEN quotedprice ELSE 0 END) AS potentialtravel,
SUM(CASE WHEN (status = 'Closed' or 'Confirmed' or 'Open') and (class = 'travel') THEN quotedprice ELSE 0 END) AS actualtravel,

SUM(CASE WHEN (status = 'Canceled' or 'Unconfirmed' or 'Communicating') and (class = 'suv') THEN quotedprice ELSE 0 END) AS potentialsuv,
SUM(CASE WHEN (status = 'Closed' or 'Confirmed' or 'Open') and (class = 'suv') THEN quotedprice ELSE 0 END) AS actualsuv,

SUM(CASE WHEN (status = 'Canceled' or 'Unconfirmed' or 'Communicating') and (class = 'minivan') THEN quotedprice ELSE 0 END) AS potentialminivan,
SUM(CASE WHEN (status = 'Closed' or 'Confirmed' or 'Open') and (class = 'minivan') THEN quotedprice ELSE 0 END) AS actualminivan

FROM `reservations`
WHERE pickuploc = 'la'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(pickupdatetime, '%m/%y'), YEAR(pickupdatetime)
ORDER BY YEAR(pickupdatetime), DATE_FORMAT(pickupdatetime, '%m/%y')
```

I want to get the combined values of `quotedprice` for `status` `Canceled`, `Unconfirmed`, and `Communicating` for `local` class and then the combined values of `quotedprice` for `status` `Closed` or `Confirmed` or `Open` for `local` class. I am trying to do this again for each class (local, travel, suv, minivan) but it is not giving the correct output, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: piggybacking on @Strawberry, what is the data you're looking at? What are you expecting to see? What are you actually seeing? Without these debugging is a lot more guesswork than actually trying to identify and solve the problem.

Comment: The data I am seeing is simply not the correct values of the data I am trying to query it is for sure a problem with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the expressions like:

```
WHEN (status = 'Canceled' or 'Unconfirmed' or 'Communicating')
```

are wrong, because they are equivalent to:

```
WHEN (status = 'Canceled' or 0 or 0)
```

and finally equivalent to just:

```
WHEN (status = 'Canceled')
```

because the strings `'Unconfirmed'` and `'Communicating'` are implicitly converted to integers since they are operands of a boolean expression.
What you should do is change the expressions like:

```
WHEN (status = 'Canceled' or status = 'Unconfirmed' or status = 'Communicating')
```

or:

```
WHEN (status in ('Canceled', 'Unconfirmed', 'Communicating'))
```